# SharePoint 2013 Management Shell; Variable is Not recognized and therefore the account attached to the variable cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint-2013, hyper-v, powershell-5.1

I am developing a SharePoint2013 instance in Hyper-V using Windows2012R2. Currently I am struggling to attach credentials to a variable in SharePoint Management Shell and then attach that variable to a New SharePoint account.

After I run the following script(s) I received this error:

Script(s):
"Variable" = Get-Credential "Domain\Username"

New-SPManagedAccount -Credential "Variable"

Error:
New-SPManagedAccount -Credential "Variable" : Some or all identity references could not be translated.

---

Essentially the new SharePoint account cannot be created and attached to the variable because the account cannot be found.  However the first script worked, so I am lost as to where or how the Variable stored the "Domain\Username".

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
$cred = Get-Credential  
New-SPManagedAccount -Credential $cred
```

For more information, you could read this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spmanagedaccount?view=sharepoint-server-ps#examples

Comment: Thank you for the assist. The issue was missing modules and incorrect paths. SMH, always gotta check those paths.